# How to make rsync faster?

Tags: sqlite, backup, rsync

I'm using rsync to sync two disk's (**in the same machine**, say `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`) sqlite DB files. On each my program start, I must run rsync to backup the 2 disk like that:

```
$ rsync -rtv /path/to/sqlite_db/ /path/to/sqlite_db_bkup/
```

Each time, there may be 500G sqlite DB files to be synced, and this will takes about hours to complete, is there some option that can make the rsync more faster? Or is there any other tools to backup so many DB files in a short time?

Comment: is it one big file or many small files ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're trying to sync databases bound in large files, i.e. you're not sync'ing the only values that changed, but the whole database all the times.

If you've got a "last time modified" column in each table you edit, or at least in the tables of the strong entities), you'd run a sql export of all the modified entities (and all the related tables) and import them in the (backup?) other drive.

Otherwise no, you'll have to backup the whole SQLite files all the times.

Answer (score 0):

If files are quite big and only show little modifications between two syncs, it can be successful to use the `--no-whole-file` option.

But, in that case both source and destination are first read, to compute chunk checksums, then delta are read from source and copy to destination.

That's why this option (delta-transfer algorithm) is activated for remote copy but not for local copy.

Have a try.